# how to prove recursive function f(x) is in O(n)?

Tags: induction, asymptotics, recursion

> Let f(n) be defined recursively as follows: $$\begin{align}f(0) &= 0 \\ f(n) &= f\left(\left \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right \rfloor\right) + 3f\left(\left \lfloor \frac{n}{5} \right \rfloor\right) +n,\quad\forall n \ge 1 \end{align}$$ Show that $f(n)\in\mathcal O(n)$.

I find some similar question that $f(n) = 2f\left(\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor\right) + 1$, but I don't know how to deal with the  $\left \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right \rfloor$ and $n$. can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: sorry,you are right,I have made it correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us prove that $f(n)\le 30n$. It is true for $n=0$. Suppose it is true for every $m< n$. Then $f(n)=f(\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor) + 3f(\lfloor\frac{n}{5}\rfloor ) )+n\le 30\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor+90\lfloor\frac{n}{5}\rfloor+n\le
10n+18n+n<30n$. Q.E.D.

Comment: thank you very much! I am trying to understand your prove process. It means that if for all m<n ,f(m)<=30m,and since floor(n/3) and floor(n/5) are both less than n,so floor(n/3)<10n and floor(n/5) < 18n,right? And I also want to ask that do I have to claim that f(n) is non-decreasing?

Comment: No, since $\lfloor n/3\rfloor <n$, $f( \lfloor n/3\rfloor} <30*\lfloor n/3\rfloor$. I do not assume that $f$ is non-decreasing.

Comment: I understand,thank you professor.

Comment: The qiestion still looks unanswered. If you are satisfird with an answer, you shoild accept it.

Comment: sure,thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Since $n$ is positive and the initial condition is non-negative, it is easy to show that $f$ is non-decreasing. So,

$$ 
f(\lceil n/3\rceil) \leq f(n)
$$

Comment: Sorry, I submitted by mistake. I'm trying to delete this answer